# Are tube fittings a feasible way to create tight seal?

Tags: pressure, pressure-vessel, seals

I'm doing an experiment where 2 electrodes are inserted into 2 openings in a cylinder holding electrolytes to measure its impedance. We want the openings to be tightly sealed because the cylinder holding the electrolyte will be pressurized. Our idea is to insert the electrodes through the holes of tube fittings. The tube fitting will screw onto the threaded cylinder and it will lock into the electrodes. Will this work, and what type and size of tube fitting should I use for this? Please give any other suggestions.

[image]

Here's a picture of what it looks like. The cylinder will be remade with only 2 holes. That's the electrode with a rod attached. We're hoping the tube fitting will dig into the rod. The diameter of the rod is about 1/4 in.

Comment: Could you add some more information or even a picture, drwaing, ...


Datasheets for fittings usually have some inforamtion about pressure they should withstand. You might want to look into that.

Comment: Search for "cord grip", or "cable gland". That's what you need.

Comment: What diameter are the electrodes? I did something similar using brass pipe connectors (1/4") which had olives that tighten down onto the electrodes.

Comment: What pressure will the chamber connections need to seal?

Comment: Not to be repetitive ; but it makes a dramatic difference if you mean several psi. or many thousands of psi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment about connectors or fittings with olives, consider something like this as the olive will compress around the electrode and usually seal nicely.

These can be had with tapered or metric threads, you will need to tap the cylinder as needed. PTFE tape can be used on the thread into the cylinder and can also be put around the olive to aid the seal.

[image]

Another possibility is to use chamfered holes and a fixing plate so that those rubber seals you show get compressed onto the electrode.

Comment: Can you give a specific one that I can use with minimal diameter to fit the cylinder? I really don't know much about tube fittings, thanks.

Comment: @HongWeiChen while I chose a fitting based on the diameter of the rod you gave, the diameter of the fitting will need to match the hole that you have to tap into the cylinder.

Comment: The diameter of the hole can be adjusted because I can just remake it, I just need the fitting to match the rod.